# What module to export to query Mongodb Atlas in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, node-modules

I am trying to connect my Nodejs app to Mongodb Atlas database (I tried with local database uri but it failed too).
The problem I see is in the object that I use for querying the database.

Here's the code that I tried

`database.js`

```
const {MongoClient} = require('mongodb');
const uri = 'mongodb+srv://myname:pass@myClustername.1unxr.mongodb.net/myDbname?retryWrites=true&w=majority';
// all fields in uri were correctly placed.

const client = new MongoClient(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });

client.connect(err => {
  //const collection = client.db("test").collection("devices");
  // perform actions on the collection object

  module.exports = client;

  //client.close();
});
```

then in `users.js`

```
var client = require('../database');

client.db('mydbname').collection('collname').findOne({"Name": "loop"})._id;
// and other queries etc
```

In the browser, it says

> Client.db is not a funtion

Also, there is

> Topology is Closed

I have tried many other things and combinations they didn't worked too like

```
module.exports = {

  connectToServer: function( callback ) {
    MongoClient.connect( uri,  { useNewUrlParser: true }, function( err, client ) {
      _db  = client.db('mydbname');
      return callback( err );
    } );
  },

  getDb: function() {
    return _db;
  }
};
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried logging/inspecting the content of `client` after `var client = require('../database');`?

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is asynchronous, use async/await to handle async code.

```
require('dotenv').config();
let { MongoClient } = require('mongodb');

const url = 
`mongodb+srv://${process.env.DB_USER}:${process.env.DB_USER_PASSWORD}@
${process.env.DB_CLUSTER}.mongodb.net`;

async function connectDatabase() {
    const client = await MongoClient.connect(url, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
});
const db = client.db("main");

return {
    listings: db.collection("test_listings")
   };
};

module.exports = { connectDatabase };
```

Comment: Are you returning a document of my collection from the `connectDatabase` function? Can you show how you query that in my `users.js`. Also wouldn't `return db` be less complex than this.

Comment: connectDatabase() function is used to connect atlas database.
const db = client.db("main"); // used to connect db "main"
return {
    listings: db.collection("test_listings")
   };
}; //will return "test_listings" collection

Comment: Okay, but in `users.js` after `var client = require('../database');`, if I do `client.find().toArray(function(err,result) { console.log(result) });` it says `client.find` is not a function

Comment: client.connect(err => {
  //const collection = client.db("test").collection("devices");
  // perform actions on the collection object

  module.exports = client;

  //client.close();
});// module.exports = client; should be last line of code, outside of loop